# How to store and retrieve associative array from database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to store Stat and End time for each Day.
These Select elements refer to 'Start Time' and 'Ending Time'
I am able to get the values but I am not sure how to store and retrieve them in my view. I am storing them by combining both arrays with the days separately and then `json_encode` but I am not able to retrieve them.

Store Blade View

```
<div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Monday" id="flexCheckDefault">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                                                Monday
                                            </label>

                                            <div class="reveal-if-active">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <label for="which-dog">From</label>
                                                        <select name="from[]" class="form-control">
                                                            <option value="1">01:00</option>
                                                            <option value="2">02:00</option>
                                                            <option value="3">03:00</option>
                                                            <option value="4">04:00</option>
                                                            <option value="5">05:00</option>
                                                            <option value="6">06:00</option>
                                                            <option value="7">07:00</option>
                                                            <option value="8">08:00</option>
                                                            <option value="9">09:00</option>
                                                            <option value="10">10:00</option>
                                                            <option value="11">11:00</option>
                                                            <option value="12">12:00</option>
                                                            <option value="13">13:00</option>
                                                            <option value="14">14:00</option>
                                                            <option value="15">15:00</option>
                                                            <option value="16">16:00</option>
                                                            <option value="17">17:00</option>
                                                            <option value="18">18:00</option>
                                                            <option value="19">19:00</option>
                                                            <option value="20">20:00</option>
                                                            <option value="21">21:00</option>
                                                            <option value="22">22:00</option>
                                                            <option value="23">23:00</option>
                                                            <option value="24">24:00</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <label for="which-dog">To</label>
                                                        <select name="to[]" class="form-control">
                                                            <option value="1">01:00</option>
                                                            <option value="2">02:00</option>
                                                            <option value="3">03:00</option>
                                                            <option value="4">04:00</option>
                                                            <option value="5">05:00</option>
                                                            <option value="6">06:00</option>
                                                            <option value="7">07:00</option>
                                                            <option value="8">08:00</option>
                                                            <option value="9">09:00</option>
                                                            <option value="10">10:00</option>
                                                            <option value="11">11:00</option>
                                                            <option value="12">12:00</option>
                                                            <option value="13">13:00</option>
                                                            <option value="14">14:00</option>
                                                            <option value="15">15:00</option>
                                                            <option value="16">16:00</option>
                                                            <option value="17">17:00</option>
                                                            <option value="18">18:00</option>
                                                            <option value="19">19:00</option>
                                                            <option value="20">20:00</option>
                                                            <option value="21">21:00</option>
                                                            <option value="22">22:00</option>
                                                            <option value="23">23:00</option>
                                                            <option value="24">24:00</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="days[]" value="Tuesday" id="flexCheckChecked">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                                                Tuesday
                                            </label>

                                            <div class="reveal-if-active">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                                        <label for="which-dog">From</label>
                                                        <select name="from[]" class="form-control">
                                                            <option value="1">01:00</option>
                                                            <option value="2">02:00</option>
                                                            <option value="3">03:00</option>
                                                            <option value="4">04:00</option>
                                                            <option value="5">05:00</option>
                                                            <option value="6">06:00</option>
                                                            <option value="7">07:00</option>
                                                            <option value="8">08:00</option>
                                                            <option value="9">09:00</option>
                                                            <option value="10">10:00</option>
                                                            <option value="11">11:00</option>
                                                            <option value="12">12:00</option>
                                                            <option value="13">13:00</option>
                                                            <option value="14">14:00</option>
                                                            <option value="15">15:00</option>
                                                            <option value="16">16:00</option>
                                                            <option value="17">17:00</option>
                                                            <option value="18">18:00</option>
                                                            <option value="19">19:00</option>
                                                            <option value="20">20:00</option>
                                                            <option value="21">21:00</option>
                                                            <option value="22">22:00</option>
                                                            <option value="23">23:00</option>
                                                            <option value="24">24:00</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                                        <label for="which-dog">To</label>
                                                        <select name="to[]" class="form-control">
                                                            <option value="1">01:00</option>
                                                            <option value="2">02:00</option>
                                                            <option value="3">03:00</option>
                                                            <option value="4">04:00</option>
                                                            <option value="5">05:00</option>
                                                            <option value="6">06:00</option>
                                                            <option value="7">07:00</option>
                                                            <option value="8">08:00</option>
                                                            <option value="9">09:00</option>
                                                            <option value="10">10:00</option>
                                                            <option value="11">11:00</option>
                                                            <option value="12">12:00</option>
                                                            <option value="13">13:00</option>
                                                            <option value="14">14:00</option>
                                                            <option value="15">15:00</option>
                                                            <option value="16">16:00</option>
                                                            <option value="17">17:00</option>
                                                            <option value="18">18:00</option>
                                                            <option value="19">19:00</option>
                                                            <option value="20">20:00</option>
                                                            <option value="21">21:00</option>
                                                            <option value="22">22:00</option>
                                                            <option value="23">23:00</option>
                                                            <option value="24">24:00</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

controller

```
**ADD FUNCTION**

$from = json_encode(array_combine($request->days, $request->from));
$to = json_encode(array_combine($request->days, $request->to));

$business->hrs_from = $from;
$business->hrs_to = $to;

**EDIT FUNCTION**

dd((json_decode($businesses[0]->hrs_from)));
```

```
Response From Dump Die

{#1130 ▼
  +"Monday": "1"
  +"Tuesday": "1"
  +"Thursday": "1"
  +"Wednesday": "1"
}
```

Comment: I would consider saving them in a column each and not combining them, what is the benefit of you doing this?

Comment: the user will store the starting and closing time for open day of their business. and a user can have multiple businesses.

Comment: if I save them in separate columns then there might be a problem with retrieving the data for his multiple busniess. we may need a separate table for it then?

Comment: Yes if that is the case, I would create a table which has `business_id`, `day`, `start`, `end`.
Did you also think about including breaks? LIke for lunch? And how are you saving holidays or special closed days?

Comment: Yes, it will have business_id and maybe user_id too? I am not including the breaks because according to requirements I only need start and end time from the user. and Yes I am saving the holidays and special days with separate ```checkboxes``` by ```exploding``` the array and then ```imploding``` it

Comment: ```'holidays' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('holidays'))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested arrays in html form input names.
For example:

```
from[day][]
from[time][]
```

or even:

```
from[day][0][]
from[time][0][]
from[day][1][]
from[time][1][]
```

It should arrive correctly on the backend.
Not sure if this helps?

I have found it especially useful with php code that has a lot of data and especially in tables.

Comment: Thank you for it. so should I use this name in the Days input or in the Starting time select input?

Comment: hmm you might need to use variables for the name. so for the day it would be from[$dayValue] and for the start time it would be from[$dayValue][$startValue]. Likely need some javascript to update the values when one of the dropdowns changes

Comment: ```from[time][monday][]``` I put the day like this and it is giving the day at the ```key``` and two arrays as starting time and end time. how do you suggest I should store it? I mean should I do ```json_encode``` or store it as text/implode.

Comment: and then what would be the best way to retrieve it? to the blade

Comment: i usually serialize the whole form with this approach

Answer (score 2):

Add second parameter to json_decode to get array

```
dd((json_decode($businesses[0]->hrs_from, true)));
```